# Longtable- Last column line is missing

Tags: tables, longtable, multicolumn

I'm trying to make a 4 column table.  However, my table doesn't have a solid line demarcating the end of the 4th column and the paper (it looks like the column has run off the page, if that makes sense). I'm new to LaTex so any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

```
\begin{center}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l} 

\caption{Supplemental Table 1- Primary antibodies used for immunocytochemistry and western blot} \label{tab:long} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Antibody}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Source}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Catalog Number}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dilution}} \\ \hline 

\endfirsthead

\hline \hline

\endlastfoot 

\hline

text & text & text & text \\\

\hline

\end{longtable}

\end{center}
```

Comment: you have `{|l|l|l|l} ` so no `|` after the 4th column. Also never put `longtable` in a `center` environment.

Answer (score 2):

You have  a specification of

```
{|l|l|l|l}
```

so no `|` after the 4th column.

Also, unrelated to the missing rule never put `longtable` in a `center` environment, it does not affect its horizontal alignment, just adds additional spurious vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `\multicolumn` command is not necessary so I suggest you to remove it. `\multicolumn` command is working fine but it could confuse the description of a table or a longtable.

Comment: this does not answer the question (which is about vertical rules) and I do not see why you say the multicolumn is unnecessary, it is quite normal to have centred headings over a non-centred column.

Comment: Removing \multicolumn command help to find the source of the trouble with vertical line in this example. As you say, that normal to have centred headings over a non-centred column so I will use it.